# Why Pt5 WIndows is very slow on start?

Tags: python, pyqt5

In this example code i run a simple GUI with a Label, i don't understand why when running the program the window is white for a couple of seconds and then becomes with the background that i wrote '#1A1A1A' and the label is displayed. Why it doesn't run directly like i programmed? Thanks

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = QMainWindow()
win.setStyleSheet("background-color: #1A1A1A")
win.setGeometry(300,300,300,300)
label = QtWidgets.QLabel(win)
label.setText('Hi everyone')
label.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow")
label.move(50,50)
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I expect to run a window normally

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Linux using Qt-5.15.9 with PyQt-5.15.9 when running the script in a standard console (i.e. not an IDE). For me, the window instantly displays a yellow label on a dark background.

Comment: I executed the script on my Windows 10 (PySide2), and it happened the same thing. The white screen is because the app is stuck on heavy processing for a few seconds (telling that the window has frozen), probably because you're inserting the _QLabel_ in the main window without setting a central widget and any layout. If I take out the _.setStyleSheet_ methods, the freezing persists. I tried to research about it, but found nothing so far. You could fix it by creating a central widget (with the dark background), add a layout to it, and add the label to the central widget's layout.

Comment: The only thing that I have found so far, was this gem from the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework): _Note: Creating a main window without a central widget is not supported. You must have a central widget even if it is just a placeholder._ So there you have it. There must be some heavy processing going on in the background, once you try to create an application without a central widget. Other than that, I have no clues.

Comment: @CarlHR Do you mean that you actually tested by setting a proper central widget and it solves the problem?

Comment: @musicamante yes, but it does not render the same result. The result is completely different from creating a central widget, setting a layout, and adding the QLabel inside that layout,    vs    inserting that QLabel directly in the main window without setting a central widget.

Comment: @CarlHR Well, that probably depends on the fact that the QSS uses generic properties instead of proper selectors. Remember that using a stylesheet like `background-color: #1A1A1A` is conceptually similar to doing `QWidget { background-color: #1A1A1A; }`. It depends on the QSS format and to what widget that QSS is applied. Still, the point remains: while what you referred above (not setting a central widget on a QMainWindow) is correct, since it's conceptually unsupported, that shouldn't theoretically cause any delay in drawing at all.

Comment: @musicamante here's the rendering output from the author's script: [image1](https://imgur.com/a/A9ilbjf), and here is my version using a central widget and a _QVBoxLayout_: [image2](https://imgur.com/a/PejjBVU). Using the 2nd output, it renders the window without freezing the application, but gives a different rendering result. Idk if that applies as an answer.

Comment: @CarlHR the difference is just because by default a widget occupies as much space as possible when added to a layout. It's unclear if the OP actually wants a "floating" label or not, but, technically, layout managers are not mandatory: can you check if the problem still exists if you just set an empty central widget and create the label as its child, without setting any layout?

Comment: @musicamante By adding these lines of code: `central = QtWidgets.QWidget()`, `win.setCentralWidget(central)` and changing the _QLabel_ creation to `label = QtWidgets.QLabel(central)`, the problem seems to be fixed. The main window doesn't freeze anymore. The problem was indeed the lack of a central widget.